# It says I've got about 3 GB and it won't let me download something for 2.2 GB. Why is it saying this and how do I successfully download it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, storage, imovie

It says I've got about 3 GB on my mac but when I try to get iMovie from the App Store (something that takes 2.2 GB) it says I do not have enough room on my Mac.

I am using an Apple Macintosh Macbook Air
Version: 10.15.7
It's also a macOS Catalina

[image]

Comment: Hi. I’ve tried to put in a question. Did I guess correctly what you seek to solve?

Comment: What are you trying to download. For example, if you are downloading a zip file and you are using the default to unzip, then there may not be enough space.

Comment: No, that's not what I seek to solve. I am using the Apple App Store. The app is iMovie.

Comment: What I seek to solve is why it is saying that and how do I download it successfully?

Comment: Thank you for the edits and clarification - much improved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration would download to the same APFS container that macOS is install to. It would not be wise to fill the container to a point where there would so little free space.

You can change the Safari preferences to ask where to download. You will need to select a location that has enough free space. Or, create more free space for the volume where Safari is currently downloading.

See the Apple website [How to free up storage space on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996).

Comment: the 3 BG is on the "Disk Space" and that is also where I am trying to download it to

Comment: If this is the same container where macOS is installed and you did succeed in downloading, then you would have less than 800 MB of free space. This would be unsafe and could lead to the computer crashing.

Comment: I was unable to succeed in downloading it - hopefully the picture helps

Comment: You are going to have to free up some space. The operating system is not going to let you do something foolish by allowing the download.

Comment: I just don't get it, it clearly says that i'v got 4.29 GB but iMovie needs 2.2 GB

Comment: @TajDaPro He's answering your question and provided a link to an Apple Support article.  You don't have enough available space for the download and the OS to run in a stable manner at the same time.  Just because you have 'available space' doesn't mean it's all there for you to use.

Comment: 4GB free space is ***critically*** low. You need 10-15% free space on any drive, ironically even more on such a tiny drive. You should be looking at freeing up 15 - 20GB to prevent your drive's early demise.